# Subsets of separable Hilbert spaces are separable

Tags: metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, separable-spaces

> Let Y be a subspace of a Hilbert space, H. Then, if H is separable then so is Y. More generally, every subset of a separable inner product space is separable.

I have been trying to prove the above result. My attempt at the proof is as follows:

Since $H$ is separable, there exists a countable subset, $W$ of $H$ such that $\overline{W}  = H$.

Let $W'=W\cap Y$. Since W is a countable set then $W'=W\cap Y$ is also a countable set. Clearly, $W' \subset Y$

Now to show: $\overline{W'} = Y$

$W'=W\cap Y \implies \overline{W'} = \overline{W \cap Y} = \overline{W}\cup\overline{Y} = H \cup \overline{Y}$

I have reached to this point and gotten stuck. Can someone help me with how to move forward in this proof?

Comment: Did you mean to write that $H'=H\cap Y$?

Comment: since $W\subset H, W\cap H=W$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am trying to show Y is separable so I am trying to prove W' is the dense countable set in Y. I have made the changes.

Comment: Does that mean “yes” or does it mean “no”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No. I have made the changes.

Comment: $W \cap Y$ could be empty. There is no guarantee that it won’t be. So the argument breaks down. Plus as a general  critique: you haven’t used *any* property of $H$. That is suspicious.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I was stuck on how to use the property of H. Is there any other way I could approach to prove this result?

Answer (score 1):

In metric space, it is separable if and only if it is second countable (having the countable neighborhood base).

Being second countable is hereditary, as intersection with the subspace.